# Factoring a polynomial with a degree of 5.

Tags: factoring

How to factor $x^5+3x^4-19x^3-43x^2-18x-40$? This polynomial was given in our activity. I'm very slow with math. Pls help

Comment: Rational root  theorem perhaps??

Comment: It may not factor nicely, e.g. after investigation of the rational root theorem. In that instance, while it may be possible to quantify the number of real roots via other methods this would not necessarily result in a simple factorization. Exercises of this type are extremely sensitive to changes in coefficients, signs of coefficients, etc. A polynomial that may work for a lot of purposes and be illustrative in a problem solving environment may become useless for those purposes if a sign is changed. So it may be worth doublechecking those as well.

Comment: This polynomial turns out to be irreducible over the rationals (as verified with Maple), but I don't know if there's an easy way to show this by hand.  Rational root theorem only rules out linear factors, you'd also need to rule out quadratic factors.

Comment: It is probably a good idea to : [1] Double check that you haven't made a typo (i.e. Rational Root Theorem was also my first guess) [2] **Meta-Cheat**, attacking the problem backwards.  What is the source of the problem?  Assuming that the problem is from a book/class, what theorems or previously solved problems led up to this problem?  What would you **speculate** is the **point** (i.e. intended educational value) of the book/class confronting you with this problem at this time?

Comment: Also: [3] Did the "activity" really require factoring this polynomial, or was it asking something else?